# TypeScript error when using d3.timeFormat in axis.tickFormat()

Tags: typescript, d3.js

This code works in JavaScript:

```
var timeFormat = d3.timeFormat("%M:%S");
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat(timeFormat)
```

But this code in TypeScript does not work:

```
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%M:%S"));
```

> function timeFormat(specifier: string): (date: Date) => string Returns
>   a new formatter for the given string specifier. The returned function
>   formats a specified date, returning the corresponding string.
>
> An alias for locale.format (TimeLocaleObject.format) on the default
>   locale.
>
> @param specifier — A specifier string for the date format.

The error is

> Argument of type '(date: Date) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null'.ts(2345)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function passed to `.tickFormat()` is passed a second argument representing the tick label's index. The method's [type definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3-axis/index.d.ts#L228) looks as follows:

```
tickFormat(format: (domainValue: Domain, index: number) => string): this;
```

The [type definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3-time-format/index.d.ts#L162) of `d3.timeFormat()`, on the other hand, looks like this:

```
export function timeFormat(specifier: string): (date: Date) => string;
```

As you can see this returns a function mapping a `Date` object to a string. This function has no second parameter and, hence, the error.

To get around this, you can explicitly cast the type of the function returned by `d3.timeFormat()` to match the one expected by `.tickFormat()`.

```
.tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%M:%S") as (dv: number | { valueOf(): number; }, i: number) => string)
```

This does not have any side effects as you can safely ignore the unused second parameter whilst still telling the compiler that you know what you are doing.

Comment: what if I have a tickFormat like this where I am conditionally formatting   
                   where I am using d3.timeFormat in a callback function?

Comment: @BoxandCox I am not sure I really understand what you are actually after. Could provide a demo or at least some snippet showing the relevant parts you are interested in?

Comment: Thanks for this answer this was one hundred percent my fault on the fact that I didn't slow down and actually read your answer thanks. I am new to Typescript so the learning curve has been a challenge. But your explanation did help me get it to work.

Comment: Thanks though this results in `Conversion of type '(date: Date) => string' to type '(dv: number | { valueOf(): number; }, i: number) => string' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.` ... typescript, sigh

Comment: Try `d3.timeFormat('%d') as (value: Date | { valueOf(): number; }, i: number) => string;`

Answer (score 15):

There's a much simpler modern solution

```
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft<Date>(y).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%M:%S"));
```

works with d3v4